# Diagonalizing blocks of the inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, diagonalization, block-matrices

Suppose I have a symmetric square matrix $\mathbb A$ in block-form:

$$\mathbb{A}= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbb{A}_{11} & \mathbb{A}_{12}\\
  \mathbb{A}_{21} & \mathbb{A}_{22}
\end{array}\right)$$

where $\mathbb{A}_{21} = \mathbb{A}_{12}^T$ and $\mathbb A_{11}$ and $\mathbb A_{22}$ are symmetric.

Now suppose I apply a similarity transformation that acts block-wise, that is:

$$\mathbb{A}' = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbb{P}\mathbb{A}_{11} \mathbb{P}^{- 1} & \mathbb{P}\mathbb{A}_{12}
  \mathbb{Q}^{- 1}\\
  \mathbb{Q}\mathbb{A}_{21} \mathbb{P}^{- 1} & \mathbb{Q}\mathbb{A}_{22}
  \mathbb{Q}^{- 1}
\end{array}\right)$$

where $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q$ are suitable invertible matrices.

Finally I invert $\mathbb A'$, and express the inverse block-form using the same layout:

$$(\mathbb{A}')^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbb{B}_{11}' & \mathbb{B}_{12}'\\
  \mathbb{B}_{21}' & \mathbb{B}_{22}'
\end{array}\right)$$

Now my question is this: Can I always choose $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q$ such that $\mathbb B_{11}'$ and $\mathbb B_{22}'$ are diagonal? If the answer is yes, can we also chose them to be orthogonal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming you're talking about real matrices. The Spectral Theorem tells you that any symmetric real matrix can be diagonalized by an orthogonal change of basis.

Comment: But the the spectral theorem is not directly applicable here. Note that I am trying to diagonalize the blocks of the *inverse*, not the original matrix itself. I think maybe the Spectral Theorem can be used here, but there are some steps missing that I can't fill in.

Comment: Yes, I meant for you to apply it to the diagonal blocks. Of course the other blocks turn into mess.

Comment: But if I diagonalize $\mathbb A_{11}$ and $\mathbb A_{22}$, that does not imply that $\mathbb B_{11}'$ and $\mathbb B_{22}'$ will be diagonal. So that's the gap I cannot fill here.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. My apologies. But it'll still work. The inverse is also symmetric, so we can apply the spectral theorem to the blocks of the inverse.

Comment: Yes but I am applying the similarity transformation on the blocks of $\mathbb A$, not on the blocks of $\mathbb B$.